# Conclude about the density of the rope being pulled by the graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

A rope of length $L$ placed straight on a frictionless horizontal floor is pulled longitudinally by a force $F$ from one of its ends. Tensile force $T$ 
developed in the rope at a distance $x$ from the rear end varies with $x$ as shown in the graph (refer the attached image). What can you certainly conclude about density of  the rope?

a) It is uniform.

b) It decreases with distance $x$ from the rear end.

c) It increases with distance $x$ from the rear end.

d) It is maximum in the middle and decreases towards the ends.

Answer is b).

[image: Graph]

Comment: What do you think the answer is, and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tension at a given point along the rope represents the force needed to pull "all the rope to the left of this point".

If you imagine the rope to be made up of a lot of very short segments (like individual cars in a very long train), then we can focus in on just one segment ("train car"). There is a force on the front of the car, pulling it and all the cars behind it; and a force on the back of the car, pulling just the rest of the train.

To balance forces, the difference between these two must equal the force of friction of that one segment of rope. If we assume Newtonian friction - the force of friction is proportional to the weight of the element of rope only - then we can tell from the slope of the curve what the weight of each segment of rope is: if the slope is steep, then the extra force needed to move one more element of rope is high; if the slope is shallow, only a little bit of force is needed.

I hope you can work your way to the right answer from here.